# Hide the x-axis, show the y-axis

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot, axis

I have the following axes code using PSTricks.

```
\psaxes[Dy=25,dy=64,Dx=32,Ox=-128](-128,-128)(-128,-128)(128,128)
```

How do I hide the x-axis but leave the y-axis remaining?

Thanks.

Comment: How about reading the documentation??

Comment: `\psaxes[xAxis=false,Dy=25,dy=64,Dx=32,Ox=-128](-128,-128)(-128,-128)(128,128)`

Comment: Reading documentation might waste much time.

Comment: The docs are very terse. I read this one but was unable to comprehend it. http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pst-plot/pst-plot-doc.pdf

Comment: @Herbert LOL...dude doesn't know how to use search